# disable the input if selected from an item

Tags: cakephp, jquery, cakephp-1.3

I have the following in my source code, I want to be able to gray out company and dock , disable if someone chooses shipping or storage

```
<select name="myselect" id="myselect">

<option value="shipping">Shipping</option>
<option value="Recieving" selected="selected">Reciving</option>
<option value="Storage">Storage</option>
</select>

company:<input name="company" type="text"  id="company" /></div>
dock:<input name="dockingStation" type="text"  id="dock" />
```

**EDIT**

I have tried this but now it removes the disabled attribut but doesnt add it back

```
  <select name="myselect" id="myselect">

        <option value="shipping">Shipping</option>
        <option value="Recieving" selected="selected">Reciving</option>
        <option value="Storage">Storage</option>
        </select>

        company:<input name="company" type="text"  id="company" **disabled="disabled**"/>
        dock:<input name="dockingStation" type="text" id="dock" disabled="disabled" />
```

and jquery is

```
$("#myselect").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val == "shipping" || val == "storage") {
         $("#company").attr("disabled", true)  // this works
```

} else {
          $("#company").removeAttr("disabled")
              .focus()
        }
    });

But now once enabled I cant disable it again

**EDIT**

WORKS NOW

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#myselect").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val == "shipping" || val == "storage") {
        $("#company, #dock").prop("disabled", true)
    } else {
        $("#company, #dock").prop("disabled", false)
    }
});
```

or if you prefer a shorter solution:

```
$("#myselect").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("#company, #dock").prop("disabled", (val == "shipping" || val == "storage"));
}).change(); // optional, set the correct state if you don't know what
             // the initial selected option will be on page load
```

Brief explanation:

- Bind an onchange handler to the select element.
- If the selected option's value is 'shipping' or 'storage', disable the two inputs, otherwise, enable them.

See:

- http://api.jquery.com/change
- http://api.jquery.com/prop/
- http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/f6AZk/

Comment: it doesnt add disabled="disabled" in the inputs

Comment: @Autolycus - what do you mean, exactly?

Comment: its not making the input disabled

Comment: You're probably using a pre 1.6 version of jQuery. I should have mentioned that `.prop` is a new method.